# How does driver signing work when Windows is offline?

Tags: windows, cryptography, driver, signing, certificate-authority

I understand the basics of signing. You must have a private key and a certificate (not necessarily) from a reputable certificate authority. You must then have the public key of the signer to verify its integrity.

I can see this working online; A site is given a certificate (not necessarily) from a reputable certificate authority (such as Verisign for example), and Firefox (for example) can check the authenticity of the certificate by contacting said certificate authority.

Yes, I know you can sign things with a self-generated certificate, but Firefox will complain when this happens and so does Windows when installing a 3rd-party driver.

My question is thus; how does windows know a driver is signed by a reputable certificate authority when it is offline and can't check with said reputable certificate authority?

Does Windows keep a collection of public keys from reputable certificate authorities within Windows? Wouldn't one be able to alter this list to load a driver as if it had the certificate of a reputable certificate authority?

How does driver signing work offline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Windows keeps a collection of trusted root certificates.  Some software, such as IE and Chrome, uses that collection; some software, such as Firefox, ships with its own list.  That's how certificate verification works; nobody gets root certificates from the CA over the internet, because how would you know you were really talking to the CA?

You can view the Windows root certificate store using MMC, via the Certificates plugin.  Note that each user account has its own certificate store, in addition to the global ("Computer account") store.

However, Windows does *not* use that list of trusted certificates for driver signing.  Instead, the Windows kernel has a built-in list of root certificates.  Certificate verification for drivers is based on that built-in list, which, if I understand correctly, consists entirely of root certificates belonging to Microsoft.

[When a driver is signed by a third-party certificate authority,](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549391(v=vs.85).aspx) a [cross-signed certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509#Certificate_chains_and_cross-certification) is used.

One further complication is that in most cases, device drivers are cryptographically verified in two separate ways; once during installation, and then again when the driver code is loaded into the kernel.  The verification during installation uses the main root certificates list and can be overridden on a case-by-case basis by the administrator; the verification when the driver code is loaded uses the kernel's root certificates list and cannot be overridden on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: I understand you can use MMC to view Windows's collection of root certificates, but where are the root certificates stored on Windows? Also, what kind of privileges would one need to write to the certificate store? Obviously admin or greater, but would it require admin or system privileges to read and alter the certificate store?

Comment: The physical file location doesn't matter - it's subject to change anyway.  The Certificates tool allows you to add and remove certificates, or you can do it in software using the .NET System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates API.  To manipulate the system's root certificate store, you need admin privilege.  (Keep in mind, however, that this will not let you add new root certificates for driver signing, since the driver verification mechanism does not use the root certificate store.)

Comment: Interesting. What mechanism does the driver verification mechanism use if it doesn't use the root certificate store?

Comment: I already covered that in the third and fourth paragraphs of my answer.  There are a small number of root certificates - possibly only one - built into the kernel, belonging to Microsoft.  Third-party drivers normal use a certificate signed by a third-party certificate authority, so they also have to ship with a cross-signed certificate.  The cross-signed certificate is provided to the CA by Microsoft, and proves to the kernel that Microsoft approved the CA root certificate for use with driver signing.

Comment: You mentioned that "the driver verification mechanism does not use the the root certificate store." I'd like to get a little bit low level here and ask one of two questions; 1. What method does the driver verification mechanism use to verify the integrity of the drivers being loaded? 2. What constructs on disk would this driver verification mechanism use (such as files used by the kernel to store the root certificates)? I'd like to be able to manipulate these constructs on disk and in memory (with a kernel debugger). If you don't know should there be some literature I should be reading?

Comment: What would you recommend?

Comment: My *guess* would be that the relevant certificate(s) are embedded directly into `ntoskrnl.exe` and/or `bootmgr`.  The implementation details probably aren't documented; no point in making subverting the system any easier than absolutely necessary.

Comment: I'll have a look around. Thank you! You were very informative and relevant.

Comment: @Sam What are you trying to accomplish? If you need to inject your home-brew driver to your own machine for testing purposes, you don't need to get it signed by Microsoft (and then re-signed each time you recompile it), — use the *TESTSIGNING* option in Windows bootloader.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I'm trying to ferret out a possible exploitation scenario involving driver verification certificates being stolen and used to circumvent driver signing at both the install and loading verification states of drivers on the Windows.